# $x^{5}+y=t , x^{2}+y^{3}=t^{2}$ and $ f=x^{3}y $ then$ \frac{df}{dt}=?$

Tags: calculus

$x^{5}+y=t , x^{2}+y^{3}=t^{2}$ and $  f=x^{3}y $ then$  \frac{df}{dt}=?$

I use chain rule but i couldnt result?

$\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$ am i wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly differentiate the first 2 equations

$$ 5x^4\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} = 1 $$

$$ 2x\frac{dx}{dt} + 3y^2\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t = 2(x^5+y) $$

Can you now solve for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and get the answer?